# PERT adjust most likely time with probability and duration time

Tags: planning, estimation, scheduling

I don't know if the name of the question is clear what I would like to do is:

I need to adjust the most likely time for an activity of my project in purpose of the probability of any path through the network being completed in x days must not be less than 0.94.

I know how to calculate the probability for a given time and a given path. But I don't know to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

PERT Analysis was discontinued as of MS Project 2010.  You can add this functionality back into MS Project; it is not a trivial task though.  A detailed, step-by-step explanation of how to do this can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/projectified/archive/2009/11/24/3296207.aspx